# how to add regex condition in helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

can some please help me, how to add not contains in helm chart?

{{- if contains  "sidecar"  .name }}

Used above condition it should not look for sidecar in the condition and how to add negative condition?

Answer (score 0):

In the core [Go text/template language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template), there is a `not` operator (actually an ordinary function).

```
{{- if not (contains "sidecar" .name) }}...{{ end }}
```

You can also have an empty block for the matching case, and put whatever needs to be output in an "else" block.

```
{{- if contains "sidecar" .name }}
{{- else }}
... whatever needs to be output ...
{{- end }}
```